# RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded on Creating Sales Order

Tags: netsuite

We are developing a client script that will auto update the rate or unit price (*this is a custom column), but it throws an error and I think its because if we change the rate it will auto update the unit price and after the unit price has been updated it will update the rate also, so on and so on until it reach the maximum call stack, We are looking for any workaround for this not to happen, please see my code below. Thanks

```
function fieldChanged(type, name, linenum)
{
    var context = nlapiGetContext();
    var user = context.getUser();
    var execution = context.getExecutionContext();

try {
    switch (name) {
        case "custcol_cqwst_po_uprice":
            if (execution == "userinterface") {
                var qty = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity');
                var taxCode = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'taxcode');

                if (!isNullOrEmpty(taxCode) && !isNullOrEmpty(qty)) {

                    var taxRate = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'taxrate1');
                    var unitprice = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_cqwst_po_uprice');
                    var vatRate = 1 + ((taxRate.replace('%', '')) / 100);
                    var unitRate = unitprice / vatRate;
                    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate', unitRate);
                }
            }
            break;
        //case "taxcode":
            //break;

        case "rate":
            if (execution == "userinterface") {
                var qty = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity');
                var taxCode = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'taxcode');

                if (!isNullOrEmpty(taxCode) && !isNullOrEmpty(qty)) {

                    var taxRate = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'taxrate1');
                    var rate = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate');
                    var vatRate = 1 + ((taxRate.replace('%', '')) / 100);
                    var unitPrice = rate * vatRate;
                    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_cqwst_po_uprice', unitPrice);

                    nlapiLogExecution('debug', "Rate Value", "Rate: " + rate + " Vat Rate: " + vatRate + " Unit Price: " + unitPrice + " Execution: " + execution);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
catch (ex) {
    alert("A scripting problem occurred during the onFieldChange event please inform an administrator quoting the following error: " + ((ex instanceof nlobjError) ? ex.getCode() + '\n' + ex.getDetails() : ex.toString()));
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValues()` has a fourth paramater called `firefieldchanged` which can be set to false to prevent exactly this issue

> **Using the Fire Field Changed Parameter**
>
> When creating scripts that provide the ability to watch a field for a
>   change, and then write back to the field that changed, a risk of
>   creating an infinite loop exists as follows:
>
> 1. The Client script watches for fieldA to change.
> 2. fieldA changes.
> 3. The script writes to fieldA, causing the Field Changed event to fire,
>      returning the code to step 2, and this loop repeats indefinitely.
>
> To prevent this looping behavior, you can set the optional
>   `firefieldchanged` parameter in your client scripts.
>
> The `firefieldchanged` parameter is available for all write functions.
>   If set to true, the parameter causes any field changed events to fire
>   as normal. This is the default setting. If set to false, field changed
>   events are NOT fired.

- https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3042487.html#bridgehead_N3050839

Comment: Thanks I forgot about that firefieldchanged. It helps a lot.